# Difference between template argument deduction for classes and functions

Tags: c++, templates

**What the problem is:**

I'm trying to implement a class that will have two specializations, one for integral types and one for all others.
The first version that came to my mind:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, bool> = true>
class Test
{
};
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_integral<T>::value, bool> = true>
class Test
{
};
```

But GCC fails with the following error when I try to [compile](https://godbolt.org/z/hefKvMzqj) the code above:

```
<source>:2:84: error: template parameter 'typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<_Tp>::value, bool>::type <anonymous>'
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, bool> = true>
                                                                                   ^~~~
<source>:6:85: note: redeclared here as 'typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Tp>::value), bool>::type <anonymous>' 
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_integral<T>::value, bool> = true>
                                                                                    ^~~~
```

However, using a similar technique for functions [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/PWGqbeMP5) without problems:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, bool> = true>
void test()
{
}
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_integral<T>::value, bool> = true>
void test()
{
}
```

**What I am trying to achieve:**

1. First of all, I want to understand why the version with functions compiles, but the version with classes does not.
2. My second goal is to implement a class that satisfies the conditions that I specified at the very beginning.

**What I have tried:**

Using partial specializations solves problem 2:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<typename T, bool = std::is_integral<T>::value>
class Test;

template<typename T>
class Test<T, true>
{
};
template<typename T>
class Test<T, false>
{
};
```

But this approach is bad because it allows to use `Test<float, true>` and if I understand correctly (please correct me if I'm wrong), then specialization for integral types will be used, which is not what I want.

**Summarizing:**

I'll just duplicate my goals in the form of questions:

1. Why does the version with functions compile, but the version with classes doesn't?
2. How can I implement a class that satisfies the conditions that I specified at the very beginning?

Comment: I think variadic template can be used here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `std::enable_if` in the template parameter list of a class is not guaranteed, since the standard only has SFINAE for functions, not for types. For types it may be available, but only as a non-standard compiler extension.

C++20 adds concepts to the standard, which does work for template parameters on template classes too.

```
template<class T>
concept NotIntegral = !std::integral<T>;

template<class T>
class Test;

template<std::integral T>
class Test<T>
{
public:
    void operator()() const
    {
        std::cout << "integral\n";
    }
};

template<NotIntegral T>
class Test<T>
{
public:
    void operator()() const
    {
        std::cout << "not integral\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "float: ";
    (Test<float>{})();
    std::cout << "int: ";
    (Test<int>{})();
}
```

---

For prior versions of C++ you could add a `static_assert` to the class body which doesn't prevent the user from specifying an invalid value for the second template parameter, but at least compiling the code will yield a compiler error of your choosing:

```
template<typename T>
class Test<T, true>
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral_v<T>,
        "The second template parameter must contain true if and only if the first template parameter is an integral type");
};
```

You could introduce a function for creating a the object instead of providing allowing the user to create objects with invalid template parameters though:

```
template<typename T, bool = std::is_integral<T>::value>
class Test;

template<class T>
Test<T, std::is_integral<T>::value> MakeTest()
{
    return {};
}

template<typename T>
class Test<T, true>
{
    friend Test<T, std::is_integral<T>::value> MakeTest<T>();
    Test() = default;
public:

    void operator()() const
    {
        std::cout << "integral\n";
    }
};
template<typename T>
class Test<T, false>
{
    friend Test<T, std::is_integral<T>::value> MakeTest<T>();
    Test() = default;
public:

    void operator()() const
    {
        std::cout << "not integral\n";
    }
};

int main()
{

    std::cout << "float: ";
    MakeTest<float>()();
    std::cout << "int: ";
    MakeTest<int>()();
    // Test<int, false> test; // would yield a compiler error because of the inaccessible default constructor
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for such a detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

Without concepts, you can do partial specializations in a more "private" way, like this:

```
namespace detail {
template<typename T, bool>
class Test;

template<typename T>
class Test<T, true>
{
};

template<typename T>
class Test<T, false>
{
};
} // namespace detail

template<typename T>
using Test = detail::Test<T, std::is_integral<T>::value>;
```

Side notes: you don't need two partial specializations, you can use the main definition for one of the values `true` or `false` (without specifying it), and you might want to rename the main `Test` class to something else, perhaps `TestImpl`; it doesn't matter to the user.

---

I'd like to provide one more alternative. I think it's important to remember that, if your two specializations are fairly similar, you could just use `if constexpr` (C++17) or tag dispatching instead of partial specializations:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Test
{
public:
    void operator()() const {
        if constexpr(std::is_integral<T>::value) {
            std::cout << "integral\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "not integral\n";
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test<float>{}();
    Test<int>{}();
}
```

Comment: `if constexpr` is by far the most intuitive approach IMO and the one we used in the production of a mature project.